Benefits of Zambian spouse visa
I am a European citizen, married to a Zambian spouse. The Zambian government gives a quite specific list of requirements for a so-called spouse visa.
However, I cannot find the benefits of such a visa. Specifically, my questions are:

How long is such a visa valid for?
How long can I stay in Zambia for with such a visa?
Can I work in Zambia?
Can I start my own business in Zambia?


From the Department of Immigration application website it shows that the validity of a spouse permit is 2 years.
Article 23 of the Immigration and Deportation Act of 2010 states that:

The holder of a spouse permit may not engage in work, except if such spouse is issued with an employment permit separately.

